# how to Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network?

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have a WI-FI  & LAN network at office. I have all my files on my desktop computer (192.168.1.2) and want to access local host over there from another computer (192.168.1.8).

My xampp version is v3.2.2 and windows 7 64 bit.
On my desktop I can access localhost through the normal http://localhost. Apache is running on port 80 as usual.

Exactly what do I have to do to achieve this? There is documentation on the net but they either don't work me or are too old and confusing to understand.

Any ideas as to what changes to make it possible? Please give me step by step instructions.

Answer (score -1):

User should have access of your localhost, you can check this by sharing the folder and check on other machine that folder is accessible or not, If it is accessible then that user easily can access your local host by using the http:/IPAddress, If not contact to IT department they will help to achieve this by removing some restriction on network.

Comment: I don't want to share files or folder. I have developed a website in my computer and want to show this site to other computer through a LAN connection. Just I have typed http://localhost/mysite and I can see in my computer browser. Similarly other's computer in a LAN can access this site.

Comment: just check the IP by pinging on other machine that they are able to access your IP or not if they can then they can also access your localhost as well.

Comment: with ip address 192.168.1.2 it's show only localhost dashboard page.

Comment: with 192.168.1.2/mysite not opening and i cant access phpmyadmin page.

Comment: Try to open this at your local machine with 192.168.1.2/mysite, If it is working then it should on other machine as well

Comment: My problem is solved. Now I can access mysite from remote computer, but css and images file not showing...what I'm missing?

Comment: please set the css and image path properly, or do check the path on other machine that address is correct or not in html source by using, inspect element from developer toolbar, or by F12

Comment: if I define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.1.2/sdnews');  
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.1.2/sdnews');  
It's working properly in both machine, but then I can't login wp-admin.